# How to save pandas.DataFrame.to_csv to a weblink?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to save my `dataframe` to a weblink like on a github repository. Any idea, if this is possible. Simply to output a `csv` from a `dataframe`, we do

```
 df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Now, I am working on a virtual environment and want to save output file in a repository/any cloud storage. Any suggestion would help.

Comment: This sort of thing isn't built into pandas - you have to interact with the cloud storage API and save contents of the dataframe into the storage. For example, to save to Amazon S3: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't output dataframe to a web link directly but we can use some libraries to store in cloud like `S3 - AWS`. You may try `Boto` library in python to output and save dataframes to `S3` storage on `AWS`. You may read the documentation here Link: https://github.com/boto/boto3

Comment: yeah I tried for json files. True, I also found its not possible to save on a weblink